# HTML Form Number Type Unique User Input with Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, unique

This question is a follow up to what I previously asked ([HTML Form Number Type Unique User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901387/html-form-number-type-unique-user-input)) but now I'm making the form more dynamic.

The following form asks users to list there 3 favorite genres of music:

```
<form id="genre" name="genre" method="post" action="musicsell.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="Rap" value="Rap"/>Rap<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="HipHop" value="HipHop"/>HipHop<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="RnB" value="RnB"/>RnB<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="Rock" value="Rock"/>Rock<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="Jazz"value="Jazz"/>Jazz<br />

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
    <br />
  </p>
 </form>
```

From there, I am using the following code to make sure that they only use numbers 1,2, and 3 and a foreach loop to list what they have checked but how can I make sure they do not use the same number twice?

```
<body>
 The genre(s) you selected are: <br />
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="musicresults.php">
  <?php
   $name = $_POST['genre'];

   if(isset($_POST['genre'])) {
    foreach ($name as $genre) {  
     ?>

     <input type="number" required="required" id="<?php echo $genre ?>" name="music[<?php echo $genre ?>]" max="3" min="1" />
     <?php echo $genre ?>
     <br /> 

     <?php
    }
   }
  ?>

  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</body>
```

This was the old javascript code from the previous question but now the id="" is generated by PHP above:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function item() {
        cake = Number(document.getElementById('cake').value);
        twizlers = Number(document.getElementById('twizlers').value);
        taffy = Number(document.getElementById('taffy').value);
        if (cake == twizlers) {
           alert("Some alert cake or twizlers");
        return false;
    } else if (twizlers == taffy) {
        alert("Some alert taffy or twizlers");
        return false;
    } else if (taffy == cake) {
        alert("Some alert taffy or cake");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }
 </script>
```

How can this be done now? Does it have to be in a foreach loop? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they hack the form or build their own POST submission, they can't "use" the same checkbox twice. But you can easily check for duplicate values:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_values($_POST['genre']));
foreach($counts as $form_value => $cnt) { 
    if ($cnt > 1) { 
        echo "$form_value was entered more than once";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code work on submit? Is there a javascript client side version I could use?